# Net framework not installing under windows 7

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework

I have a small app that requires net framework 4.7.2.
When I install it, i get the following error:
"Net framework 4.7.2 is not supported on this OS" (windows 7).
Is there a workaround?

Comment: Please provide any errors you are receiving when you attempt to instal .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Try this ..

    https://stackoverflow.com/a/75883840/11780141

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 7 Service Pack 1 is a requirement, so make sure you have that installed.

See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements for more information.